# Is it possible to programmatically open, edit, and save rtf files using Office 2010 from a Java app?

Tags: java, ms-office

A task I'm working on has grown. I need to open up some rtf documents using Office 2010, edit them, and then save them. Is there a way to automate this programatically using Java 6? I'm not aware of any java open source offerings that can run Office 2010 for something like this or what options there are for this type of task?

Comment: What I left out, that I should have mentioned, is that we are upgrading to a newer version of Office, so the requirement is to run the documents through Office 2010 to open them, make a small change, then save them. Then I take the rtf's and run them through our 3rd party reporting software to ensure everything still works as before without problems with fonts, spacing, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the java.lang.Runtime and java.lang.Process to execute external programs through a sort of command line approach.  Check the exec method in Runtime which uses a String[], it's the one that gives you program and argument options.

Process:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Runtime:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Here is a general idea of how it's used
http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

Also here is a little bit about opening Word through a command line approach
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565

I've used this approach myself to open files in notepad and such

However, if you want to open these files and apply some automated edit to them, there may be a much different way of doing that, that may not require Word.

Comment: Excellent answer! This looks like something I'll try. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html), which allows you to read write and manipulate RTF files

Answer (score 0):

RTF is just text. The simplest solution that I can think of to to create the template document in Word and save as RTF. Then you can perform string replacement in the text file. A quick test of $HelloWorld$ work just fine so let's assume that single fields are no problem.